# How to place this code inside a php file

Tags: php, html

Im getting error. I dont know how to place this inside php file.

```
<?php
    <form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQsXMUh"
        data-amount="999"
        data-name="Stripe.com"
        data-description="Widget"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true">
      </script>
    </form>
?>
```

Comment: Learn it from here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: what is the error ?  html should not be inside of php tag

Comment: <?php  ?> <form> .. </form> put your code like this

Comment: if you want use html inside the php tag use echo like this <?php echo '<form>...</form>';

Comment: i tried echo. it gives "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" method="' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/market58/public_html/stripe.php on line 2

Comment: try this <?php ?> <form> .. </form> put your code like this @RajaTamil

Comment: @JYoThI that would work. but the whole page is in php. and it has to go inside..

Comment: you can open php tag anywhere like this <?php ?> <form> .. <?php ?>
 </form>  <?php ?>    but you need to open and close properly .

Answer (score -1):

Bro I think you are a new starter. Only PHP code is written within  in a .php file. HTML, CSS and Javascript codes are not written within it. They can be written in a .php file as you write them in a .html file.

```
<?php
echo "heloo"
?>

<div>LOL</div>
```

I hope it was useful.

Answer (score -1):

**You can Use this Code Like That**

```
<?php
    echo '<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_tkn67XnFEh5CYrLDZFtmDXoL"
        data-amount="999"
        data-name="Stripe.com"
        data-description="Widget"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true">
      </script>
    </form>';
?>
```